# Remove the first line of a string in Liquid template

Tags: liquid

Suppose I have a string containing multiple lines in a Liquid template,
how can I remove the first line of a string? ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to preserve `<br />` tags in the string,
or your string does not contain br tags at all:

```
{% assign page_content_lines = page.content | newline_to_br | split: '<br />' %}
{% assign page_content = '' %}
{% for line in page_content_lines offset:1 %}
  {% assign page_content = page_content | append: line %}
{% endfor %}
```

Brief explanations:

1. In Liquid, there is no methods like `rest/cdr` or `pop` for arrays, so I have to write a for loop.
2. `split: '\n'` does not work since Liquid does not recognize the `\n` notation. Therefore, I have to convert newlines to br tags first.